# Why is Rails looking for an ID for my #collection# route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have...

**routes.rb**:

```
  resources :standards do
     collection do
        get :none
     end
  end
```

I get the following with `rake routes`:

```
none_standards GET    /standards/none(.:format)                  standards#none
```

I have the following in my `standards_controller.rb`:

```
def none
end
```

So why do I get a "Couldn't find Standard without an ID" error at /standards/none?

With `better_errors`, it says:

```
(gem) activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb
  305 
  306       ids = ids.flatten.compact.uniq
  307 
  308       case ids.size
  309       when 0
  310         raise RecordNotFound, "Couldn't find #{@klass.name} without an ID"
  311       when 1
  312         result = find_one(ids.first)
  313         expects_array ? [ result ] : result
  314       else
  315         find_some(ids)

...

Instance Variables

@table  
#<Arel::Table:0x007fc321207650 @name="standards", @engine=Standard(id: integer, name: string, description: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime), @columns=nil, @aliases=[], @table_alias=nil, @primary_key=nil>
@klass  
Standard(id: integer, name: string, description: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

It's a collection route not a member route, so this seems very odd.

Comment: How does your `rake routes` output look in regards to this route?

Comment: added details to my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with `declarative_authorization`. I had to change `filter_resource_access` (which assumes regular routes) to `filter_access_to :all` (which covers all routes) in `standards_controller.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

strange!, for me it works with the following setup (just check what your routes says)

```
#app/controllers/standards_controller.rb
class StandardsController < ApplicationController
   def none

   end 
end

#config/routes.rb
resources :standards do
  collection  do
    get :none
  end
end
```

my routes are

```
none_standards GET    /standards/none(.:format)     standards#none
     standards GET    /standards(.:format)          standards#index
               POST   /standards(.:format)          standards#create
  new_standard GET    /standards/new(.:format)      standards#new
 edit_standard GET    /standards/:id/edit(.:format) standards#edit
      standard GET    /standards/:id(.:format)      standards#show
               PUT    /standards/:id(.:format)      standards#update
               DELETE /standards/:id(.:format)      standards#destroy
          root        /
```